# How can I expose my url in a friendly way for Primefaces+JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, friendly-url

I need to expose my application url in a friendly way. For example while viewing the users , the current url is like, `http://localhost:8080/userview.jsf` for all. But I need something like `http://localhost:8080/user/view/1`  where 1 is the `id` for the first user.How can I bring this to my application.
**I am using Primefaces.3.0.M3 with JSF2**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reproduce specific Friendly URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174487/how-to-reproduce-specific-friendly-url), [Remove faces servlet url pattern and page extension from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514132/remove-faces-servlet-url-pattern-and-page-extension-from-url), [Bookmarkable URL in JSF application - Trying to use Spring Webflow and JSF . Any suggestions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775884/bookmarkable-url-in-jsf-application-trying-to-use-spring-webflow-and-jsf-any) and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettyfaces can help I think http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Answer (score 1):

Preetyfaces will help you to make website url google friendly like we did in our website www.askkuber.com...We are using JSF2 and Primefaces with Preetyfaces.